# Orange Data Mining SQL table connection error - extension "quantile" not supported

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, orange

I am using Orange (via Anaconda) to connect to a PostgreSQL database on Amazon RDS, but when I try to connect, I get the following error: 'Extension "quantile" not supported by Amazon RDS'

[Orange SQL Table connection error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajA7Q.png)

I am using Orange version 3.14.0, and the Postgres instance is 9.5.10

Is there a setting in Python/Orange I can turn off, to prevent this extension being called/loaded?

Answer (score 1):

The fix is already pending a merge: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/3097

Comment: Got it! For some tables I can try loading completely into memory, but good to know a fix is on the way.